# how to apply CSS styles in current document recieved from AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an AJAX request, that returns a few CSS IDs, like:

```
#id1{something:something}
#id2{something:something}
#id3{something:something}
...etc ect
```

Is there any way I could add these ID's to the current document (the document that made the AJAX request) using Javascript/JQuery?

I make the AJAX request, using JQuery and JSON variables, if that helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using AJAX to fetch the CSS and then worry about inserting it into the document, you could just dynamically add a `<link>` tag to the document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..." />
```

The `href` should then include the required parameters needed by the CGI script.

```
var url = "......"; // including parameters

var script = $('<link>', {
   rel: 'stylesheet',
   type: 'text/css',
   href: url
}).appendTo(document.head);
```

The browser will then automatically trigger the loading of the new CSS file.  If you wish to catch the completion of that you should be able to add a `.load()` handler.

Answer (score 1):

you can create/edit a `<style>` tag and put your stuff there, the browser will recognize it and apply it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have your AJAX function return a JSON object like

```
var data = {id1: {something: something}, id2: {something: something}, id3: {}}
```

and apply that using

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
    $('#' + index).css(item);
});
```